# Show localhost:38000 application in some URL defined by .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, proxy

I think this is called some rewrite -proxy thing but I cannot understand how to set it up. Basically, I have an application in localhost:38000 and I want to show it up in mySite.com/test, how can I do that?

`RewriteRule ^localhost:38000$ http://mySite.com/test/$1 [P`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/test(/.*)? http://localhost:38000$1 [P]
```

Comment: where do you specify the mySite.com/?

Comment: In the `<VirtualHost>` block where you're putting your `RewriteRule` directives. I assume you already have a `VirtualHost` for your `mysite.com` site, and you are only configuring your proxy for the `/test/` path.

Comment: I don't have access to server configuration files so I cannot configure this with VirtualHost but only with .htaccess.

Comment: Then you don't need to care where to put `mysite.com`, because when apache reaches your .htaccess, it already knows it is serving `mysite.com` (which I assume is the domain of your hosting account for which you're configuring .htaccess)